# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2) when import .xlsx file extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem when import the excel file, when extension is.xls its working properly but when extension is .xlsx it give argument errors.

```
def open_spreadsheet(file)

  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 Roo::Excel.new(file.path, packed: false, file_warning: :ignore)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation, Roo::Excelx.new (initialize method) only takes two arguments.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/roo/Roo/Excelx

Change line 6 to:

```
when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, :ignore)
```

Comment: But if I do this, its give me "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem, doing some changes in that case

```
 when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, packed: nil, file_warning: :ignore)
```